# Program doesnt enter foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

This is my code:

```
private List<Picture> items;

public List<Picture> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            items = new List<Picture>();
            items = this.LoadAllItems();
        }

        return items;
    }

    set
    {
        this.items = value;
    }
}

public List<Picture> GetItemsBySearch(string searchTerm, string fieldName)
{
    DataAccess dbcontext = new DataAccess();
    string internalfield = dbcontext.GetInternalFieldNameByDisplayName(fieldName);
    List<Picture> PictureHits = new List<Picture>();

    var data = from Picture item in this.Items
               where item.GetType().GetProperty(internalfield).GetValue(item, null).ToString().Contains(searchTerm)
               select item;  

    foreach (Picture item in data)
    {
        PictureHits.Add(item);
    }

    return PictureHits;
}
```

The `data.Count` contains 88 items but it does not enter a `foreach` loop.

Does the `var` not work within a `foreach` loop?

`Picture` is a class with some objects like `filename`, `ID`, etc.

[image]

This is what "data" contains so it contains 88 items doesnt it?

Comment: any error? have u debug? put a try..catch will help u a lot

Comment: your code sample even will not compiles

Comment: `from Picture item in this.Items`??? should be `from item in this.Items`

Comment: Just a remark: the line `items = new List<Picture>();` in the getter is useless. You can just remove it.

Comment: it compiles, i dont get errors.
It just seems like "data" doesnt contain items

Comment: when you debug this do you have any items in your data object?

Comment: How about `PictureHits = data.ToList();` does that work ? if it still doesn't check if you have optimized code checked or if you are debuggin in release mode. Some breakpoints wont get triggered in those modes

Comment: "The data.Count contains 88 items" No, it shows that *source* contains 88 items, which is the original List, aka `Items`. Data has no Count property.

Comment: Expand the results view. It vill not yield any results. Your predicate therfore does not match a single entry. As @Dennis_E said - its the source of the enumerable before the filter.

Comment: if I try `PictureHits = data.ToList();` PictureHits Count is 0
Maybe my where is not working?

Comment: @Julian yes, the where is not working

Comment: @Julian contains is NOT case sensitive. This must be your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem might be in where condition

```
var data = from Picture item in this.Items
               where item.GetType().GetProperty(internalfield) // threre
                   .GetValue(item, null).ToString().Contains(searchTerm) // might bean issue
               select item;
```

try to comment it and repro. If foreach will work, then you have criteria which is filtered all your data.